# IPhone WebApp Specific Keyboard for Float-numbers

Tags: iphone, layout, keyboard, floating-point, iphone-web-app

Im working on a small WebApp for my iPhone.

I got a form with some input-fields for text, numbers and float-numbers.
Until now i used the normal qerty-layout but i know that special apps can use specific keyboard-layouts for input-fields.

I already found out how to get a normal 0-9-keyboard, but i need the "," or "." for float-numbers.

So my question: is it possible to display the a 0-9-layout including the "," or the "."

Greets :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Supported Input Values](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/InputTypes.html)

```
<input type="number" >
```

Displays 0-9 in the top row and punctuation below for me in iOS 5.

Comment: AWESOME! Thats exactly what i was searching for :)